# how to get datetime instance?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Well it is look like simple question. but i am in the learning stage can`t figure out.

This is my model class

```
class Store(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    userfild = models.ForeignKey(user,null=True, blank=True)
```

Ok for some clarification i just included my content_file_name function here

```
def content_file_name(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join(
      "user_%d" % instance.created_date, filename)
```

but the output of the folder structure looks like this

```
`None`
----filename
```

i can get the file_name instance like this --> `intance.file_name`

but when i enter `instance.created_date` it is return `'None'` value.

What i am missing.? And my another doubt is i set it DateTimeField as auto_now_add=True So it`s saved into the db when form is submitted. But why None return?

Comment: Is your model backed onto a database? Does the instance of the model you are ?fetching? actually have a non-null created_date in the DB? If you could post a little example of how you are using the Store class it will help!

Comment: @TomDalton Yes i am using MySql to store the value. I can able to see the instance using ubuntu workbench. Yes i want to fetch the instance of the created_date back from the db. No.There is no Null value in db, All i can see is the date posted there. What example you want ?

Comment: Is your DB schema properly synced to the model? Could you post the output of a simple 1-row SQL select query on the store table?

Comment: @TomDalton but after file upload i can able to see datetime entered in db. My question why it`s return none value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`auto_now_add` is not populated until the object is saved. If you want a default that is applied as soon as the object is instantiated, use the `default` parameter with a callable:

```
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure that this is what you're asking, but here goes anyway:

You create an instance of any class by instantiating it:

```
Store()
```

In Python, this calls the class's **init**() function. Since you don't have one, it will use the 'constructor' from the class you're inheriting from, models.Model.

So, for example, you could do something like this:

```
my_store = Store()
my_store.file_name = 'some new name!'
```